# If referrer (multiple&exact) than div else div two

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I've got this code working for one referrer (twitter) but how do I amend so if there was from twitter and facebook and further how do I amend to be exact root domain eg from only checking t.co to t.co/s9NHw3

```
<script>    
console.log(document.referrer);
console.log(document.referrer.split('/')[2]);

if (document.referrer.split('/')[2] === 't.co') { 
    document.getElementById('imagebanner').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('others').style.display = 'none'; 
} else {
    document.getElementById('imagebanner').style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById('others').style.display = 'block'; 
}
</script>
```

Example of what I have tried:

```
<script>    
console.log(document.referrer);
console.log(document.referrer.split('/')[2]);

if (document.referrer.split('/')[2] === 't.co/s9NHw3','facebook.com') { 
    document.getElementById('imagebanner').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('others').style.display = 'none'; 
} else {
    document.getElementById('imagebanner').style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById('others').style.display = 'block'; 
}
</script>
```

Edited question. Please see issue below in comments. I am now looking want to look at tag only in url (not even root url) and then show either div one if it has tag in url (example bing.com/eu9jdi9 or google.com/eu9jdi9 - where eu9jdi9 is the tag - would like to use multiple tags so will try || again) or div two if it hasn't.

Comment: Try this: `if (document.referrer.split('/')[2] === 't.co/s9NHw3' || document.referrer.split('/')[2] === 'facebook.com')`

Comment: @sideroxylon thanks for your help. It works but I have another problem instead and was hoping someone can aid in this. When I am using bingads (Bing ad network) I don't know who the referrer is (can be multiple, I asked customer service- they don't know). Instead I can tag it. Is there anyway we can do the show div one and not div two if it has a certain tag in the url rather than splitting the url and looking at domain root only?

Comment: Yes.  `if (document.referrer.indexOf('[tag]') !== -1) {`.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot